# google play application upload failed

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

apk upload failed to the google play market.

I am trying to upload the upgraded version of my app to the google play but I am keep getting the message -

```
Upload failed

You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.
Your APK needs to have the package name com.corntail.project.
```

There is still something that is looking for `com.corntail.project` and it is not being found.

UPDATE:

In my `AndroidManifest.xml`, the relevant code is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.corntail.main"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: did u change the version code in your AndroidManifest.xml ??

Comment: but what about the second part- its still saying that `Your APK needs to have the package name com.corntail.project.`

Comment: posted. My package name is - `com.corntail.main` but it is keep on saying that `Your APK needs to have the package name com.corntail.project.`

Comment: did you change your package name in this version? looks like your previous version had the package name as 'com.corntail.project.'

Comment: My Version Code had been updated to 3 but the manifest had not been saved. I fixed that...
The package is set to `com.corntail.main` and there is not a choose to select `com.corntail.project`. Do I just type that in or is there a configuration step I am missing?

Comment: what is the package name of your launcher activity?

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Android Studio or building with gradle, edit your gradle script (**build.gradle**) to change your package name and version. These values overwrite your AndroidManifest.xml file.

For example:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your `android:versionCode="1"` to 2 on the AndroidManifest...

Comment: The Google Play Upload still errors with the missing package name error. However my package name is- `com.corntail.main`

Comment: Have you changed your package name? You need to set the same as the previous version you uploaded, in this case `com.corntail.project` you cant change your package name between versions. Set `package="com.corntail.main"` to `com.corntail.project`

Comment: But I will be able to submit the app again with a different name? Can I delete the current and Submit again as corntail?

Comment: You can change the app name but not the package name.

Comment: If I change the app name, then it will be treated as different app but not the update of the current app in google store. So should I delete the current one in order to submit my new one?

Comment: If you change the app name it will NOT be treated as a different app. The play store only differences package names. And you can't delete a submitted app only unpublish.

Answer (score 3):

Things you have to keep in mind when updating your application on Google Play :

1. Change Version code +1 depending on the old value - if it's 1 , you have to change it to a bigger number.
2. Change your App Version Name to something bigger / different if it's string -  if your old version is 1.0 - it should be 1.1 / 1.0.1 or whatever you like (it's always a better option t have some version name strategy, if it will contains the date update addded or the revision it depends on you).

And if you want to be able to update your app, don't change project package name! That's how android system knows that this application is different than that one. If you change your package name, it's now acting like a new app and you won't be able to update it from Google Play Store! To change your package name to `com.corntail.project` first you need to change it in manifest and after that in your project's main package and you need to keep track of your activities, if you declared them with package name too. For example :

if your MainActiivty was declared in manifest like :

```
com.corntail.main.MainActivity
```

you need to change it now to be like :

```
com.corntail.project.MainActivity.
```

Comment: But I will be able to submit the app again with a different name? Can I delete the current and Submit again as corntail?

Comment: Yes, you can delete the old one and upload the new with the new package name, but remember to update your version code and version name to 1 and 1.0 too.

Comment: But after deleting the old one, if its new app, do I still need to update the version code and name?

Comment: That depends on you, it's just better when releasing a new app in the store versions code/name to start from 1 and above. Don't forget to keep the same package name the next time when you will try to update your app!

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use a different version code for your APK because you
>   already have one with version code 1.

You must change your version code in your `androidmanifest.xml`

Comment: The Google Play Upload still errors with the missing package name error.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you update your app change this variable in you XML file:

```
android:versionCode="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 errors.

- The Version Code: you always need to set a higher number in the versionCode and always use an integer number. (don't use 1.1)

  android:versionCode="1"
- The package name: it has to match the same string that you used in the latest version that you upload. So instead of package="com.corntail.main" you should use:

  package="com.corntail.project"

After modify the AndroidManifest.xml save it and then search in the folder src the package called "com.corntail.main", right click, Refactor > Rename, and the new name should match what you put in package (in this example you should call it: 'com.corntail.project') and you are done!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have change version code in increasing order i.e. 1,2,3...so on as every time you uploaded. In every upload version code should have greater number than previous upload version code. You can change version code in APP Module Build.gradle file.

### [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUgba.png)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build with gradlew, you should check the build.gradle file,
the applicationId will overwrite the package value in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
    }
}
```