# Android upload new apk to production failed: Use different version code

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I've build an app using PhoneGap and I used PhoneGap Build to build the actual apk. Initially I uploaded an apk, realised that there was a bug. I then unpublished it and am now at the stage where I have to re-upload a new apk. However when I do I get the following error:

[image]

My initial idea is that I have to change something in my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.example.myapp" 
        version="1.0.0" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        versionCode="1.0">
.....
```

Though I've tried changing both instances where there's a reference to 'code 1' and nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use another version code. You can't publish twice. Just increment the version code.

Comment: And this you do somewhere in the build apk file or in Google Play it self?

Comment: try like versionName="1.0.1" and  versionCode="2", then take signed build and try to upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google play application upload failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542147/google-play-application-upload-failed)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config.xml

change this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.prosperitygroup.EmedEmergency" 
        version="1.0.0" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        versionCode="1.0">
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.prosperitygroup.EmedEmergency" 
        version="1.0.1" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        versionCode="2">
```

I am assuming here that your config.xml is a wrapper for AndroidManifest.xml inside Cordova (or the new build.gradle way of increasing version numbers).

If you do have an AndroidManifest then you want something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prosperitygroup.EmedEmergency"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
```

You must increase the version number of your app when uploading a new version, you can increase the number by 1, 2 or any other numerical number.

You should increase the version number for every bug fix that you check in to source control. That way you can keep track of bugs easier.

For example, if you check in a bug fix with build number of 1.8 and someone reported the bug in 1.7 then you can tell the person to simply update for a bug fix.

I try and increase my version code with every bug fix I make, when I close a bug report, I make a note of the new build code so that I know to ignore bug reports from users on an old version which has the bug present

What is the difference between versionCode and version?

`Version Code`

> — An integer value that represents the version of the application
>   code, relative to other versions. The value is an integer so that
>   other applications can programmatically evaluate it, for example to
>   check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set the value to
>   any integer you want, however you should make sure that each
>   successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative.

`android:versionName`

> — A string value that represents the release version of the
>   application code, as it should be shown to users. The value is a
>   string so that you can describe the application version as a
>   .. string, or as any other type of absolute or
>   relative version identifier.

You can read more about them here in the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/versioning.html):

Comment: Thank you @apmartin1991 I'm rebuilding now to see if it works. So I guess the real question is: What's the difference between version and versionCode?

Comment: Brilliant, very clear and I've tested it, and it worked. Thanks again :)

Comment: Please mark the question as correct (click the tick) if it helped :) Your very welcome, clear answers are always the best. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your manifest, there is a attribute for versionCode and versionName as such:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.basiccontactables"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

You need to update those two variables each time you want to publish another version of your apk.

Comment: Thank you, that does shed some light on the situation. However where do you apply this in Cordova/PhoneGap?